# .NET Core published project always redirects to Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

the url is randomly redirected to  Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2 while any action. is there a problem with the code? I've been dealing with this error for a long time and i suspect that the startup middleware order does not correct. i shared the most important parts of startup.cs below.

`Configure`:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, UserManager<AppUser> userManager, RoleManager<AppRole> roleManager, IWebSiteBussRepository webSiteBussRepository)
        {


            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }


            IdentityInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager).Wait();
            IdentityInitializer.StaticPage(webSiteBussRepository).Wait();

            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/StatusCode", "?code={0}"); 
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
         

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                     name: "areas",
                     pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                     );
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                   );
            });



        }
```

`ConfigureServices`:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
            services.AddDI();//custom Startup Collection
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>();
            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>
            {

                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

            }).AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityValidator.CustomIdentityValidator>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddAuthentication();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options => options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(5));
     services.Configure<EmailOptions>(Configuration);
           
             services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {

                options.Cookie.Name = "sitename";
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(20);
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
                options.LoginPath = "/Home/SignIn";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/AccessDenied";
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something I spot out till now is that `services.AddAuthentication();` only register the middleware for authentication process, it doesn't point-out which scheme to use for the authentication process.

Even when we have `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie`, that's only configure for `CookieAuthenticationOptions`, it doesn't register and make use of `CookieAuthenticationHandler` yet. In-fact... I'd be surprise if the code actually worked.

Anyway... I still recommend the clear way

```
services.AddAuthentication(opts => opts.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Cookie.Name = "sitename";
        cfg.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        cfg.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        cfg.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(20);
        cfg.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
        cfg.LoginPath = "/Home/SignIn";
        cfg.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/AccessDenied";
    });

// drop services.ConfigureApplicationCookie below
```